# Duplicate error creating synonyms

Tags: sql, oracle, toad, synonym, ora-00955

I am attempting to create synonyms for a user in Oracle.

```
BEGIN
    FOR S IN (SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables WHERE owner = 'TABLE_OWNER') LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create synonym '||S.table_name||' for '||S.owner||'.'||S.table_name||'';
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I get the following error in Toad when executed:

> Error at line 1
>   ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
>   ORA-06512: at line 3

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the table name and owner and the synonym name and owner cannot be the same.  Only one object/owner combination may exist.  You must either change the owner or the name for the synonym from the table name.

Comment: If you are trying to make public synonyms then the command is create public synonym, btw.  You are probably running this as the user matching 'TABLE_OWNER', which is causing your problems.